# Dynamic library (.so) : Link time and run time

Tags: c, compilation, linker, shared-libraries

What is the main difference between using a .so file a link time or using it at run time (dlopen() etc) ?

1. What kind of validation is performed when used at link time ?
2. What is the role of the header file that lists the methods exposed out of .so and used in the target binary ?
3. How does the address space looks in both the cases ?

Comment: Regarding point 2, header files are *never* involved during link-time or run-time.

Comment: What i meant was , what is the role of header file listing the methods exposed out of the library ?

Comment: Well that's really it. Function prototypes in a header file tells the compiler that somewhere there exists a function with name this or that. The compiler doesn't know *where* those functions are defined, and doesn't really care, it just needs the declaration (prototype). Of course, header files can contain much more than just function prototypes, like structure definitions and type-aliases.

Comment: The function prototypes are useless in run-time linking; however, structure definitions are useful. What would be *really* useful for run-time linking, but is hardly ever included, is function pointer typedefs.

Comment: So, when .so file is linked at run time, there is no validation for the actual object code is present or not ? However, we do get undefined references if the corresponding code is not found in the .so. So I believe, linker also does some check to verify the code in .so file.

Answer (score 3):

1. At link time the compiler will only check that the symbols are available in the library and will specify which library to link against later (in case you are linking against multiple libraries providing the same symbol)
2. The header file will only tell the compiler of what function prototypes are available and (depending on the programming language used) how to translate them into symbols. e.g. C++ `extern "C"`.
3. If you are linking against a library then the linker will create a global address translation table in the executable which will be populated with the symbol addresses at runtime when the library is loaded. If you are opening the library with `dlopen` then you are responsible of creating variables holding the symbol pointers yourself via `dlsym`, but it allows you more flexibility like e.g. changing those during runtime, loading plugins or other functions that are unavailable at compile time.